# Microsoft graph service subscription ExpirationDateTime never expire

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I have an Office365 Web API to fetch mail from the following URL:

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me

I have created a subscription for getting notifications from the graph service. However, I can not set the expiration time for the subscription to more than 4230 minutes. While I [searched](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/subscription) in Microsoft website I got this default time. While I add more than **4230 minutes** in the request to the Graph I get `BadRequest` error code.

Following is the request code:

```
Subscription subscription = new Subscription
{
    Resource = "me/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages",
    ChangeType = "created",
    NotificationUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:NotificationUrl"],
    ClientState = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), ExpirationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow + 
                  new TimeSpan(0, 0, 11115, 0) // shorter duration useful for testing
};
```

Can anyone suggest me how to override the default time in the graph API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/subscription), it tells you that the *maximum* expiration time is 4230 minutes

[image]